# Estou tentando criar um TRIGGER BEFORE AFTER mas da um erro de variável não declarada no IF da trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Estou tentando criar uma trigger before insert na minha tabela Consultas mas o erro 1327 aponta que a variável tipoConsulta não está declarada;

Trigger BEFORE INSERT da tabela Consultas:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `agendadeconsultorio`.`consultas_BEFORE_INSERT` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `consultas` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF tipoConsulta = "M" THEN
        SET 
            data := NEW.data,
            hora := NEW.hora,
            ordem := NULL;
    ELSE
        SET 
            data := NEW.data,
            hora := NULL,
            ordem := ordem + 1;
    END IF;
    
END
```

Abaixo a tabela da trigger acima

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Consultas (
  
  id int primary key,
  ordem INT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nomePaciente VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  nomeMédico VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  data DATETIME,
  hora TIME,
  tipoConsulta ENUM("M","O"),
    
    FOREIGN KEY(nomePaciente) REFERENCES Pacientes(nome)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
        
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: É Oracle o Mysql ou ambas , triggers são objetos que dependem da sintaxe do Banco.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Opa, tudo bom?
Antes de utilizar as variáveis, instância elas na triagger, dessa forma:

```
    CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `agendadeconsultorio`.`consultas_BEFORE_INSERT` 
    BEFORE INSERT ON `consultas` 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    DECLARE data DATE;
    DECLARE hora TIME;
    DECLARE ordem INT;
    DECLARE v_tipoConsulta CHAR;
SELECT tipoConsulta INTO v_tipoConsulta FROM consultas_BEFORE_INSERT order by registro_sequencial desc;

        IF NEW.tipoConsulta = "M" THEN
            SET 
                data := NEW.data,
                hora := NEW.hora,
                ordem := NULL;
        ELSE
            SET 
                data := NEW.data,
                hora := NULL,
                ordem := ordem + 1;
        END IF;
        
    END
```

Me avisa se funcionar